# How can I automatically save the docker logs in the host

Tags: docker

I have a web app that is running through docker container in a server where if I need to debug I use **docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER** to find the problem.

I would like to have my container log on my host instead to connect on the docker to see it.

Comment: are you using node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look into `-v`option of docker run command.

> **-v=[]:** Create a bind mount with: [host-dir:]container-dir[:rw|ro].
>          If 'host-dir' is missing, then docker creates a new volume.
>          If neither 'rw' or 'ro' is specified then the volume is mounted
>          in read-write mode.